# Tensorflow installation on FreeBSD hosting

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, freebsd

I wrote python image recognition system based on tensorflow, but can't install tensorflow on hosting. My hosting is mydevil.net. Tried using pip install tensorflow but it didn't work. I would like to add that the hosting works on a FreeBSD system.

Answer (score 0):

TensowFlow is a complex piece of software that isn't easy to port/package. At the moment there is a package for TensorFlow v1 only: https://www.freshports.org/science/py-tensorflow/